Abrir .exe desde mi proyecto con Visual Basic
Quiero ejecutar un .exe que generé, el cual me deja abrir de forma manual sin ningún problema.
Esta es mi funcion:
Public Sub RunExe(filePath As String)
    Dim run As Long
    MsgBox(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory)
    Try
        run = Shell(filePath, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error al ejecutar el archivo: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Le paso la ruta exacta en una variable pero me sale:
'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
trate de usar otra funcion:
Public Sub RunExecutable(filePath As String)
    Try
        ' Crear un nuevo proceso
        Dim process As New Process()
        process.StartInfo.FileName = filePath
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True ' Establecer a False si no es necesario usar el shell del sistema para iniciar el proceso
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False ' Establecer a True para no mostrar una ventana de consola si no es necesario

        ' Iniciar el proceso
        process.Start()

        ' Opcional: Esperar a que el proceso termine
        process.WaitForExit()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Manejar cualquier error que pueda ocurrir al intentar ejecutar el .exe
        MessageBox.Show("Error al ejecutar el archivo: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Pero en esta me sale el error:
'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in System.dll y un mensaje de exception de "access is denied"
Alguien sabe porque podria pasar esto o si saben otra forma de ejecutar un .exe?
este .exe debe abrir una consola cmd.

que tiene filepath en la primera version???

Para ambos casos el filepath contenia una ruta como string 'C:\Users\Yo\Downloads\Proyectos\nuevo\Cruce1.exe'

Puedes ignorar los mensajes de error de esta manera:
Public Sub RunExe(filePath As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim run As Integer
    ' MsgBox(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory)
    run = Shell(filePath, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)
End Sub


El OP indica que desea abrir un .exe desde su proyecto con Visual Basic, Revisa [answer]

Le sale el error porque intenta meter un integer dentro de un long y si no lo abre es por tema de permisos, ya que el comando shell no debería de fallarle.
Shell no solo abre exe también abre documentos aunque no es el caso.

El error le viene de usar un msgbox con formato de C# en visual basic. El objeto  MessageBox no se si le ira muy bien hay... mejor usar MsgBox("MsgBox")
